# How to set specific specs to run in each machine with cypress parallelization in azure-pipeline

Tags: javascript, parallel-processing, grouping, azure-pipelines, cypress

- I'm using azure-pipelines CI to run my cypress tests, I runs my files in parallelization on two different machines at the same time to decrease the total time, Cypress parallelization divides the files **depending on the time each one take**, But i want to divide the files on each machine **depending on my selection** (for ex. each folder on different machine), How can i do that?

Note: grouping can't help in my case.

Comment: Could you share how did you set cypress parallelization currently?

Comment: I set parallelization setting in my pipeline as Multi-agent and set the agent = 2, 
Then i run using this command
`npx cypress run --ci-build-id $BUILD_BUILDNUMBER --group "paralell" --record --key=$CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY --spec "cypress/integration/Par*/*" --parallel`

Comment: Have you checked the links I provided in the reply? Are they helpful?

Comment: Unfortunately not, i couldn't pass each matrix suite for each machine

Comment: Did you consider setting two pipelines?

Comment: Yes, do you have .yml file example of how to pass run command for each machine?

Comment: I mean you could set up multiple pipeline to run the tests (each pipeline for each folder), and use `demands` keyword to specify the agent you want to use: `pool:
  name: MyPool
  demands:
  - agent.name -equals ComputerName`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#demands

Comment: Is my reply helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following discussions:

- https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3657
- https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-documentation/issues/922

You could try [matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#matrix) in pipeline:

```
- template: e2e-template.yml
parameters:
  pool: E2E
  url: https://yourwebsite.com
  maxParallel: 2
  matrix:
    suite_1:
      suites: 'testFolder/suite_1/*.*'
    suite_2:
      suites: 'testFolder/suite_2/*.*'
```